# Hook on Google page result load

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, userscripts

The purpose of a userscript I'm writing is changing the order of the Google buttons when searching to a permanent one (as well as adding the Discussions option). [This is the situation without the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epBf3.png) and [this is with the script.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x841I.png)

The problem is that my hook isn't fast enough to seemlessly change the content of the page. Because Google dynamically loads the page, it can't just run from the beginning. As of now I tried to fix it with a mutation observer.

```
var hasChanged = false;
MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
    var i =0;
    while(i < mutations.length && hasChanged === false){
        if(mutations[i] !== undefined) {
            if(mutations[i].target.getAttribute('class') === 'hdtb-mn-hd') {
                changeLayout();
                hasChanged = true;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
});

observer.observe(document, {
  subtree: true,
  attributes: true
});
```

But it doesn't always hook on the right moment and is generally too slow. An example of the problem can be seen in this [gif/html5 video](http://gfycat.com/VerifiableAdeptBrontosaurus). When first searching it shows the slight delay. When clicking on Discussions, it shows the hook not loading. When refreshing the page, it shows the delay again.

[Link to the full script](http://pastebin.com/J26r8S4g)

Comment: "...and is generally too slow".....

would it be possible to break the for loop after the "hasChanged = true;" line?

Comment: Do you mean the while loop?

Comment: sorry...i must have been tired when i looked at it. setting hasChanged = true does break the while loop because hasChanged === false breaks it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Google Button Fixer
// @namespace   googlebuttonfixer
// @match       https://www.google.tld/*
// @include     https://www.google.tld/*
// @exclude     https://www.google.tld/maps/*
// @require     http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js
// @grant       none
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

// Prmitive settings menu. (Don't use an option twice)
// Options: web, images, maps, videos, news, books, apps, discussions
newMainLinks = ["web", "discussions", "images", "maps", "videos", "news"]
newMenu = ["books","apps"]

function changeLayout(){
    var url = window.location.href;
    var isPrimary = false;
    if(url.indexOf("tbm=") < 0)
        url += "&tbm=dsc"
    else{
        var urlArray = url.split("&")
        for (var i = 0; i < urlArray.length; i++) {
            if(urlArray[i].indexOf("tbm=dsc") >= 0)
                isPrimary = true;
            if(urlArray[i].indexOf("tbm=") >= 0)
                urlArray[i] = "tbm=dsc";
        };
        url = urlArray.join("&");
    }

    var discussionsLink = $('<a />', {
        "class": 'q qs',
        "text": 'Discussions',
        "href": url
    })

    var discussions = $('<div />', {
        "class": 'hdtb_mitem'
    }).append(discussionsLink);

    if(isPrimary)
        discussions.addClass("hdtb_msel")

    $("#hdtb_msb").append(discussions);

    var mainLinks = $("#hdtb_msb .hdtb_mitem").detach();
    var moreMenu = $("#hdtb_more").detach();
    var searchTools = $("#hdtb_tls").detach();

    placeLinks(newMainLinks, $("#hdtb_msb"), mainLinks);
    placeLinks(newMenu, $("#hdtb_more_mn"), mainLinks);
    $("#hdtb_msb").eq(0).css("margin-left", "130px");
    if(newMenu.length > 0)
        moreMenu.appendTo($("#hdtb_msb"));
    searchTools.appendTo($("#hdtb_msb"));
}

function placeLinks( linkArray, target, mainLinks){
 i = 0;

 while(linkArray.length > 0){
    var href = $("a", mainLinks.eq(i)).attr("href");
    var testParam = href;
    if(href === undefined)
        testParam = window.location.href;
    if(testParam.indexOf("tbm=isch") >= 0 && linkArray[0] === "images"){
        mainLinks.eq(i).appendTo(target);
        linkArray.splice(0, 1);
        i = 0;
    }
    else if(testParam.indexOf("tbm=vid") >= 0 && linkArray[0] === "videos"){
        mainLinks.eq(i).appendTo(target);
        linkArray.splice(0, 1);
        i = 0;
    }
    else if(testParam.indexOf("tbm=nws") >= 0 && linkArray[0] === "news"){
        mainLinks.eq(i).appendTo(target);
        linkArray.splice(0, 1);
        i = 0;
    }
    else if(testParam.indexOf("tbm=bks") >= 0 && linkArray[0] === "books"){
        mainLinks.eq(i).appendTo(target);
        linkArray.splice(0, 1);
        i = 0;
    }
    else if(testParam.indexOf("tbm=dsc") >= 0 && linkArray[0] === "discussions"){
        mainLinks.eq(i).appendTo(target);
        linkArray.splice(0, 1);
        i = 0;
    }
    else if(testParam.indexOf("maps.google") >= 0 && linkArray[0] === "maps"){
        mainLinks.eq(i).appendTo(target);
        linkArray.splice(0, 1);
        i = 0;
    }
    else if(testParam.indexOf("tbm=app") >= 0 && linkArray[0] === "apps"){
        mainLinks.eq(i).appendTo(target);
        linkArray.splice(0, 1);
        i = 0;
    }
    else if(linkArray[0] === "web") {
        mainLinks.eq(0).appendTo(target);
        linkArray.splice(0, 1);
        i = 0;
    }

    i++;
}
}

//do not run in frames or iframes
if(window.top == window.self) {
    MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver
    if(MutationObserver) {
        var observerAll = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
            //#hdtb_msb is the container of all buttons
            if($('#hdtb_msb').length) {
                observerAll.disconnect();
                changeLayout();
            }
        });
        //wait until #hdtb_msb exists
        observerAll.observe(document, {
            attributes: true, 
            subtree: true
        });
    }
}
```